# JQuery intelli not supported in Razor pages?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I don't see any intelli for JQuery in Razor pages.

Comment: Does your Razor file have a script tag referencing JQuery?

Answer (score 2):

Add a script reference to the vsdoc.js file and intellisense will work:

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.4.1-vsdoc.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

[image]

Comment: For intelli to work I need to add that vsdoc on each page than its working. If I have ascx controll like Header and putting that vsdoc file in it will not work for other pages. Isn't there any central place to put it so all the pages load the JQuery intelli?